# DFA to RE conversion but what if init and final state same?

Tags: regex, dfa

[image: Example]

I can't figure how can i solve this problem. Could you guys help me?

Comment: Identity of initial and final state implies 1 special case, otherwise apply the standard techniques for the conversion. You certainly know how to cater for a finite number of special cases in a RE.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform this DFA into an equivalent NFA by adding in a new start state that ε-transitions into the old start state, then adding a new accepting state with an ε-transition from the old accepting state. That way, you don’t have to deal with the case where the start and accept states are the same, and in doing so you didn’t change the language of the automaton.

Comment: I'll try like this.